# Add multiple products to cart - bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I have custom page and products will be displayed based on my custom criteria.

each block i have

Combo 1
item 1
$7.99       Qty 1

item 2
$5.99       Qty 2

item 3
$3.99       Qty 4

item 4
$2.99       Qty 6

item 5
$8.99       Qty 2

|--------------- |
| add to cart |
|--------------- |

when i click "add to cart" all the products with quantity needs to added to bigcommerce cart.

Can you please let me know how to add multiple products with quantity to cart.

Thanks in advance.
Dhamu